# node project run on AWS EC2 instance with PM2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pm2

i have setup the node project on the AWS EC@ instance.

> ```
> npm start
> ```

is working. then project running on the **3000** port. but it will closing when close the terminal. then i have tried PM2.but when run using **PM2** its not working. but status showing as **online**.

[image]

these are the command used to run PM2,

> ```
> npm install pm2 -g
> pm2 start app.js
> pm2 startup
> pm2 save
> ```

why is that ? how can i run it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried `pm2 logs`?

Also, you can set the project for default like whenever you want to run your server you can simply run by using the `pm2 logs` command, to set up your server here is the command

Go to your source folder or where your app.js file is stored, and then run this command

```
pm2 start npm --name "Your Project Name" -- run start
```

After setting up by this, you can always run your server with `pm2 logs` command

Thanks